# How to generate code using Postman Collection

Tags: bash, postman, code-generation, postman-collection

I'm aware it is possible to generate code snippets from individual Postman requests, but I can't find similar functionality for a entire collection.
I also know that there are tools like [newman](https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman) for running an exported collection in Postman Collection 2.1 json format.

But specifically what I'm looking for is a tool that generates `bash` code from a collection or from a exported collection in Postman Collection 2.1 json format. This way my co-workers who don't use Postman can replicate the API requests.

Is this option available in Postman and I'm just missing it or are there any tools that do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended using the [Postman SDK](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-collection) and [postman-code-gen](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-code-generators#postman-code-generators-) to create code snippets from Postman Collections that I exported from Postman.

Not really sure why this feature isn't provided already by Postman, but I made a simple CLI tool that does it:
https://github.com/arashout/postman-collection-gen

```sh
# cURL request generation
node main.js -c example_collection.json

# curl --location --request GET 'https://v7rr12wbr7.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/courses?c0=PHYS153&c1=APSC160&c2=CHEM154&version_key=1.2'
# curl --location --request GET 'https://v7rr12wbr7.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/courses?c0=PHYS153'


# How to generate other languages:
node main.js -c example_collection.json -l shell,httpie
node main.js -c example_collection.json -l Swift,URLSession
```

Comment: thanks!, it needs postman-collection to be installed: npm install postman-collection --save

Comment: The postman code generation is just http client "raw" request and "raw" response. No dto/classes at all. That's why there is no tool/plugin for this.

Comment: @Cherry So Postman sucks and OpenAPI rocks?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your question completely. 
But I can tell you how I export collection and then run tests.

1. Export Collection to JSON: choose tab 'Collections' at the left tab of the Postman. Select the 3-dot menu and choose 'Export'.
2. Export your test environment: Open 'Manage Environments'. Click download.
3. I don't know a tool that generates bash code, I write it manually.

Write .sh file like the following to run your tests.

"newman run your_test_collection.json -r cli -e your_test_environment.json --reporter-cli-no-assertions --global-var"

Usually, I create different .sh files for different sets of tests.

Comment: No this isn't exactly what I want. My main use case is sharing `curl` snippets from my Collection of requests instead of having team members download `newman` or `Postman`