# Bulk export Postman collection to file containing curl requests

Tags: curl, postman, postman-collection-runner

I would like to make a bash script file from all my requests in a collection. Is there a way to do it without exporting all of them one by one?

Comment: duplicated from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60514286/how-to-generate-code-using-postman-collection